# connect to ejabberd through strophe in django

Tags: django, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to connect to ejabberd. Version of ejabberd is 18. i changed ejabberd.yml
module: ejabberd_http

```
request_handlers:
  "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/bosh": mod_bosh
  "/api": mod_http_api
##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
web_admin: true
http_bind: true
http_poll: true
## register: true
captcha: true
```

when i am using strophe to connect by

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind');
```

it says connection attempt failed and connection timeout.

Any solutions please ??

Answer (score 0):

> var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind');

You are requesting the "/http-bind" path, but ejabberd is listening in "/bosh". Change your quety, or change to config, so these paths match.